# pdo_mysql and timezonedb won't load

Tags: php, pdo, timezone

I have a problem on a web server where PHP is failing to load pdo_mysql and timezonedb extensions, the error log suggests that they are incorrectly compiled but I’ve tried re-compiling Apache/PHP via EasyApache and it’s making no odds.

I have also double checked and they are specified in /usr/local/lib/php.ini so they should load, and further the extensions_dir value appears to be correct too...

I'm at a loss as to how I would go about re-compiling these extensions with the correct extension API version... any pointers?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a configuration issue and is not programming related.

Comment: Understood - just getting desperate! Still haven't found a resolution to this but have worked around it by explicitly setting the PHP timezone in htaccess and hacking the PHP code which relied on PDO.